# How to query a custom post type using a parameter from a query string

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a custom post type call `fs_park`.  While the name/slug of the post can change, the `unique_id` of the custom post type will not.  I have a map and I have have a link like `wwww.example.com?unique_id=123456`. How can I query for a single custom post type with `unique_id=123456`?  Sorry, I have tried the following;

```
function query_fs_part_by_unique_id(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  $some_post = $request->get_param( 'unique_id' );
  return $some_post;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of unique_id you can get using $_GET, but you need to use strip_tags or esc_html for security purposes.